# Access Files on Android though HTML file input

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have a app which loads in files and displays them as text. It uses javascript and HTML, the file picker opens but when on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A running 6.0 on a account which is not the "Owner" you are unable to access the local files when using the html file input.

Using the owner account
[image: Owner file Opening]

Using another user account
[image]

Is there any way to let a none Owner access locla files though this HTML file picker, I know that if you get  athris party file manager it will show up with the onedrive and gallery tabs and you can access the file though that. But I wnat it to work with out having to install another app.

Comment: Sounds like normal user restrictions due to Rights.

Comment: Yeah, its because the Samsung have decided to give file access to the tablet owner account but not the the user account, however I want to know if there is a way to fix this, so users will be able to access internal storage, because right now "users" do not get a full experience of the application.